# Is there any reason not to clean nozzles with fire?

Tags: nozzle, cleaning

Specifically using stainless steel nozzles, but I guess it's worth knowing about brass too. Is there any reason to be concerned about dimensional accuracy of the nozzle or anything like that as a result of repeated heating with a butane torch?

Comment: The butane costs more than a brass nozzle? 

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE well i already have butane, and can get more from any gas station or hardware store. new nozzles are slightly harder to come by in a pinch

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda kidding and that's why it's a comment rather than an answer. But the point is that trying to clean brass nozzles really isn't a good use of effort/resources. They're a consumable you can buy cheap in bulk, so if you use them, just stock up.

Answer (score 4):

If you carbonize the filament or other particles that are clogging the nozzle, then you will never get them clean. In my experience, it's not worth cleaning the nozzle with anything other than cleaning filament. If that doesn't work then change the nozzle. Heating the metal nozzle with a torch will change the temper of the material. I used to try cleaning with a soldering iron; which was to no avail.

Purchase a dozen brass nozzles and save your self the headache. Either that or a good quality set of stainless steel ones. They are easier to clean with the cleaning filament and aren't ablated by the filament as quickly, allowing for better dimensional accuracy over multiple prints.

[https://www.amazon.com/eSUN-CLEANING-Filament-Printers-Cleaning/dp/B00MVIYNFW/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OhXB.jpg)

[image: eSun Cleaning Filament]

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the torch hot enough and you carbonise/burn the filament properly, it may work. You still need to do a cold pull to remove as many residues as you can, but if you heated it enough, the residuals maybe won't stick too much to the nozzle.

You already have the butane, try and tell us.